# Prove that the sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)_{n \in N} \in [0,1] = (x^n)_{n \in N}$ is not Cauchy with respect to $\|\cdot\|_\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Struggling with the problem:

> Prove that the sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \in [0,1] = (x^n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is not Cauchy with respect to $\|\cdot\|_\infty$

I have by definition that $$d_\infty(f_n, f_m) = \max_{x \in [0,1]} |x^n - x^m| = \max_{x \in [0,1]} |(x^n|1-x^{m-n}|)|$$

Then for ${n,m \in \mathbb N}$, $m \geq n$, I want to fix $n$ and show that as $m \rightarrow \infty$ in the limit this construction does not converge: i.e it is $0$ everywhere except for a point somewhere which is equal to $1$.

Help with formalising this argument?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Make sure you give your attempt at solving this problem in the question itself. This will help others answer your query.

Comment: The maximum of $x^n-x^{2n}$ is equal ${1\over 4}$ and is attained for $x^n={1\over 2}.$

Comment: Is the problem in the space $C([0,1])$?